# Can't SSH to Pi from outside my LAN

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding

I am having trouble establishing an SSH connection to my Raspberry Pi 3 from outside my LAN.

**Configuration**

- I have dynamic DNS setup using No-IP and it works perfectly for my Ubuntu 16.04 server.
- I have configured `ufw` to allow all incoming traffic to port 2224 and I have my router configured to forward traffic on external port 2224 to internal port 2224 at my Pi's static IP.
- The server that is working is setup the same way, except it is using port 2223.
- The only thing I changed in my `sshd_config` file is the port (2224).

**Tests/Actions**

- It's been rebooted multiple times and I have no problems connecting to it on the LAN from other devices.
- The router's logs also appear to be forwarding the port correctly, so it seems that it is an issue on the Pi itself.
- I'm unable to even `telnet` to port 2224 from external (it just hangs and displays nothing).
- Also, `/var/log/auth.log` does not show any authentication attempts from a public IP.

If anyone could provide any advice on what I should do next, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I bet you made some typo on the router either using wrong local IP addr in forwarding or ports.

Comment: Is the default gateway set properly for the pi?

Comment: I don't see any typo in the port forward setup on the router.
I'm using WiFi as the primary network interface (I tried ethernet, but that did not work either). For some reason it won't let me configure any statics in /etc/network/interfaces, so here is my config in /etc/dhcpcd.conf:

interface wlan0
inform 10.23.42.4
static routers=10.23.42.1
static domain_name_servers=10.23.42.1 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 0):

So it's resolved now.  Turned out to be a stupid oversight on my part.  There is no separate field for the subnet.  It must be added directly to the static IP (10.23.42.4/24).  Turns out, it defaults to /8.  Thanks for the assistance.